# What sample rate do I need to analyze usb 2 with a analyzer?

Tags: usb, usb-host, logic-analyzer

What is the sample rate needed for a logic analyzer to be able to analyze a 480 Mbps USB 2 bus?

Comment: What data rate is full speed USB 2 bus?

Comment: USB 2 FS is 12 Mbps.

Comment: USB 2 has a speed of 480Mbps

Comment: I have changed in the question with speed instead of full speed as it seems that full speed is limited to usb 1.0 specs of 12Mbps

Comment: @codiac I think Andy's comment was intended to be rhetorical. This is almost a self-answering question. Almost.

Comment: @DKNguyen Might be. Let's clarify than. I have seen in a video that analyzer speed should be 4x the speed of analyzed signal. And this was also seen some time ago in a forum post that I can't find where it was stated that it should be 5x. Don't know why, but if there is any truth behind these statements I would like to know and of course why.

Comment: @DKNguyen Not really sure why you haven't answer officially as it seems quite a good one. I understand that if there is a hardware cause one should debug with at least twice the data rate because of wave deformation. But if the use case would be to sniff and debug software of an errorless hardware, will the same rule apply?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Less than double = non-unique. A non-unique waveform reconstruction isn't worth anything.

Comment: What do you want to analyze about USB 2 HS? Logic analyzer may not be the right tool. If you want to sniff and analyze the protocol, get a protocol analyzer. If you want to sniff and analyze electrical parameters, get an oscilloscope. If you just want to look at what packets get sent and received, route the traffic via some software solution like libusb or wireshark.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was thinking that if the frequency is same and the signal is square, it will take a sample at the exact same relative time to the real tick as first sample; I know is async but I'm trying to explain in my own words. This would give the exact level of every bit transmitted. That was the thinking behind the last question.

Comment: @codiac But it won't be *exactly* the same frequency so you'll get double shots on the same bit and you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: @Justme I have seen a situation where there was a bug in the open-source firmware for a USB device where at some point there was a conflict in the transmission of both master and slave. In this conflict both, master and slave, where expecting some message from the other. One could not find the bug with Wireshark because the messages did not pass the driver. Master was expecting a ACK or a NACK or other replay from slave but the driver was locked in that state where it would not even respond to master anymore. So this case would need a hardware analyzer to sniff the communication.

Comment: 240MHZ x2 minimum preferably x4, there are two differential lines. You'll also need a logic analyzer with differential probes. It's better to have an oscilloscope with a differential probe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nyquist basically says you need at least double the bandwidth (aka the highest frequency component of interest) in your signal to get a sampled waveform unique to your signal. Unique is not the same as accurate. Draw a sine wave with just two points per cycle, then 4, then 8, then 16. You can intuitively see why. Your square wave's fundamental is around 480MHz but the edges of a square wave contains frequencies many times that. But you know it is a square wave so you can weed out things like edges that don't seem to be exactly where they should be if your sample rate isn't many times faster than double.

It is the difference between having a discernible or identifiable picture vs a clear, highly detailed picture. Sometimes, discernible is enough though, especially if you already know what it is you are supposed to be looking at.

Answer (score 3):

USB 2.0 HS signal has the main frequency of 240 MHz, but the signal UI (unit interval) is 2.083 ns. So you need few samples per UI to identify the bus state and its transitions.

There are software processing packages for high-speed oscilloscopes that provide USB protocol post-processing and decoding. For example, Tektronix offers USB decoder starting with mid-level scopes as 
4 Series MSO Mixed Signal Oscilloscope, [see this reference](https://www.tek.com/document/application-note/troubleshooting-usb-20-problems-your-oscilloscope)
[image]

In this example the default sampling rate for a straightforward signal decoding is 6.25 Gsps, but 3.125 Gsps is also doable. For more details of scope-based decoding [see this article](https://download.tek.com/document/Troubleshooting-USB2_App-Note_55W-61092-1.pdf).

However, normal USB protocol analyzers don't use the raw data sampling; they use the same high-speed grade USB PHYs as in normal USB devices, they just use a weak non-invasive high-impedance sniffers with wide-band amplifiers to restore the signal and feed the PHY. The PHY does all this oversampling (internally), clock-data extraction, and provide an output in digital format to FPGA-based buffers and event triggering.

Answer (score 2):

Since USB 2.0 hast a frequence of 480MHz you need more than the Double of this (Shannon-Theorem).

Neverthrless most often the 10 times of the frequence is recommended. So around 4800Mhz.

Comment: So will it be kind of insufficient with 1G. What if there are no errors in the transmission (hardware wise) and used only for sniffing?

Comment: 1GHz would be right on the limit, as it does not leave much room for differentiation, slightly higher than 1.06GHz would be the ideal for recovering every last bit, (with only 2 samples you get a beat frequencies that makes it hard to tell exactly where the clock is in relation to your samples, so you want atleast 2 samples per level to make this easier.